ADF Inner join returning less rows than expected
I have a very simple inner join connecting an excel file in storage, to a view in a database. The join is on a reference that exists in both data sets. However there are no results.
The schema for both data sets has been imported correctly and matches on data types.
This is a test scenario, the data in the excel file is a simple export from the view, therefore every row should in theory match.

I expect to see a 100% match for the excel file, as the rows that exist within it, were copied directly from the view which it is now being joined to.

Could you add the data preview screenshots of source1 and source2 also

The data preview for both sources shows all the data expected and all data types match in this instance. There's no obvious reason for the join to reject the key.

What is the total number of records in the excel file and sql view ? Could you share those numbers here?

In ADF dataflow data preview, join is not happening based on full data of source1 and source2. Both source1 and source2 preview data are limited to few sample rows only and not the entire data. So, there can be mismatching rows in source1 and source2. This is the reason for the less rows than expected in the output of join transformation. To solve this, you can either increase the rows limit or give the sample data for debugging. Below is the approach.

Click the Debug settings on the dataflow canvas toolbar.
In the dataflow debug dialog box, click the General tab.
To give the sample data, select the sample file in the source1 and give the sample file from the file path. Similarly give the sample file for source2 also.
Otherwise, you can also increase the row limit of data preview. Increase the row limit value from 1000 to required value. (For the large dataset, this approach is not recommended)


